# How to get all attr value in same class by click() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a Simon game, but I need to get the "id" (attribute) value. but whenever I click on the different color it still gives me the first attr value which is in this case is green. how many times do I click on the red, blue, or yellow button but it still gives me a green value (the first one). help, please!

*//Below code HTML*

```
<div class="container">
      <button class="btn green" id="green"></button>
      <button class="btn red" id="red"></button><br />
      <button class="btn yellow" id="yellow"></button>
      <button class="btn blue" id="blue"></button>
    </div>
```

*//Below code Jquery*

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    var userChosenColor =$(".btn").attr("id");
    console.log(userChosenColor);
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `$(this).attr("id")`? You use nothing specific to the clicked button in the function. Why are you surprised that `$(".btn")` has exactly the same result, not matter _where_ it’s called? The [documentation](//api.jquery.com/attr#attr1) also explains how `.attr` works.

Comment: ```$(this).attr('id')``` or ```this.id```, you need to reference the actual button clicked.

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of adding several event listeners — it’s more maintainable and applies to dynamically added elements. See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [this Q&A](/q/1687296/4642212). Use the second selector argument in jQuery’s [`.on`](//api.jquery.com/on): `$(".container").on("click", ".btn", function(){ console.log($(this).attr("id")); });`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Delegation shouldn't be used unless the elements are actually added dynamically, it has potential issues of its own. "more maintainable" is debatable, to each their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to the button clicked.
You do not necessarily need jQuery for this.

```js
$(".btn").click(function () {
    var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log('jQuery: '+ userChosenColor);
});

/* non jQuery */
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

btns.forEach(btn=> {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('JS only: '+btn.id)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn green" id="green">1</button>
  <button class="btn red" id="red">2</button><br />
  <button class="btn yellow" id="yellow">3</button>
  <button class="btn blue" id="blue">4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i am pushing my clicked data in array but only showing me numbers how many time i clicked not the data. why? help!
'var userClickedPattern = [];
$(".btn").click(function () {
    var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor));
});'

Comment: Please add a new question, as this is a different issue. Thanks.